# Change of order of integration with the inner integral being improper and uniform convergent on the integration segment of the outer integral

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, fourier-transform, absolute-convergence

Suppose $f(x),\phi(x)$ are absolutely integrable on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $g(\lambda)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$. So we have that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{g(\lambda)e^{-i\lambda x}d\lambda}$. Let's multiply by $\phi(x)$ and integrate on $[-A,A]$ both sides. According to my book thanks to the uniform convergence on $[-A,A]$ of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{g(\lambda)e^{-i\lambda x}d\lambda}$ we can change integration order and get $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f(x)g(x)dx} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\overline{\big[\int_{-A}^{A}{\phi(x)e^{-i \lambda x}dx}\big ]}g(\lambda)d\lambda}$ where the overline means complex conjugate. I don't understand though how the book reaches such a conclusion. I guess I'm missing some important property on change of order of infinite integrals. Any hint?

Comment: There is something seemingly missing here.  In the last expression, the LHS is independent of $A$, while the right-hand side is dependent on $A$.

Comment: @MarkViola Afterwards the book passes to limit when $A \to \infty$ in the expression and obtains a form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)g(x)dx} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{g(\lambda)\overline{\Psi(\lambda)}d\lambda}$. But, there is one incompatibility here. Initially the theorem was about proving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x) \phi (x)dx} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{g(\lambda)\overline{\Psi(\lambda)}d\lambda}$ ($\phi(x)$ on the left instead of $g(x)$).

Comment: P.S. for context, this is a proof of Plancherel equality.